# Decryption error: Encrypte a message on Android and decrypte on Intelij IDEA

Tags: android, encryption, rsa

My server is on Intelij Idea Windows, and Client is on Android. I send the rsa public key from server to client, which encripte message of public key and send to Server. Server getting error when decrypte a message.

I tried to use Server not on Intelij, but Android and everything worked. I also tried to swap server and client, Server - Android, Client - Intelij, and also didnt work, but the result was different: Server getted and successfully decrypte the message, but with the message was many other symbols.

This is the code, where Server - Intelij and Client - Android.

Server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5556);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
System.out.println("Client connected");

DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream dIn  = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

//Create keys
Map<String, Object> RsaKey = rsa.initKey();
String RsaPrivateKey = rsa.getPrivateKey(RsaKey);
String RsaPublicKey = rsa.getPublicKey(RsaKey);

//send key
dOut.writeInt(RsaPublicKey.getBytes().length);
dOut.write(RsaPublicKey.getBytes());
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(RsaPublicKey);

//read encrypted message
int length_pk = dIn.readInt();
byte[] message = new byte[length_pk];
dIn.readFully(message, 0, message.length);

String st1 = new String(message);
System.out.println(st1 + " " + length_pk + " " + st1.length());

String str = new String(rsa.decryptByPrivateKey(message, RsaPrivateKey));
System.out.println(str);
```

Client:

```
Socket client = new Socket("192.168.1.103", 5556);
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

//read key from server
int length_pk1 = dIn.readInt();
byte[] publickeyserver1 = new byte[length_pk1];
dIn.readFully(publickeyserver1, 0, publickeyserver1.length);
String RsaPublicKeyServer = new String(publickeyserver1);

//test key rsa
String str = "Who is there?";
byte[] encbyte = rsa.encryptByPublicKey(str.getBytes(), RsaPublicKeyServer);

dOut.writeInt(encbyte.length);
dOut.write(encbyte);
```

Rsa library:

```
public static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
public static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "MD5withRSA";
private static final String PUBLIC_KEY = "RSAPublicKey"; 
private static final String PRIVATE_KEY = "RSAPrivateKey";

public static byte[] decryptBASE64(String key) throws Exception {
   return Base64.getDecoder().decode(key);
}
public static byte[] decryptByPrivateKey(byte[] data, String key)throws Exception {
   byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

   PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
   KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
   Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
   return cipher.doFinal(data);
}
public static byte[] encryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key) throws Exception {
   byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);
   X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
   KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
   Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

   return cipher.doFinal(data);
}
public static String getPrivateKey(Map<String, Object> keyMap)throws Exception {
   Key key = (Key) keyMap.get(PRIVATE_KEY);
   return encryptBASE64(key.getEncoded());
}
public static String getPublicKey(Map<String, Object> keyMap)throws Exception {
   Key key = (Key) keyMap.get(PUBLIC_KEY);
   return encryptBASE64(key.getEncoded());
}
public static Map<String, Object> initKey() throws Exception {
   KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
   keyPairGen.initialize(1024);

   KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
   RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
   RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

   Map<String, Object> keyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);

   keyMap.put(PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);
   keyMap.put(PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
   return keyMap;
}
```

Stack Trace

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error    at
> Main.main(Main.java:110) Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException:
> Decryption error  at
> java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:369)
> at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:282)
> at
> java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:366)
> at
> java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:400)
> at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2206)  at
> main.java.rsa.decryptByPrivateKey(rsa.java:134)   at
> Main.main(Main.java:103)

I have been using the Rsa library for a long time, I don't think it's a problem. I think the problem is between IDE.

Comment: Although this may not be the problem, in general `Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm())` is not correct. For `Cipher.getInstance()` the argument should be of the form 'algorithm/mode/padding'. It is allowed to just use 'algorithm' for the argument, which is what you're doing, but it shouldn't be. When using just 'algorithm' the mode and padding used are default values chosen by the provider, and the provider is platform/environment specific, which is not what you want. Always specify the full 'algorithm/mode/padding' string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested it might be in the comments, the problem is your failure to specify the full "algorithm/mode/padding" transformation specification to `Cipher.getInstance()`. Instead, you are using `keyFactory.getAlgorithm()` as a specification. The KeyFactory algorithm just happens to return "RSA", and when you use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA")` you end with provider-specific defaults. On Android the padding default is "NoPadding" and on Java the padding default is "PKCS1Padding". It would be better to use RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding on both sides. Even better than that is the more modern but more complicated ""RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding". The `OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding` scheme itself has parameters, and again although you can use defaults they are provider-specific and thus should be avoided. You returned an initialized, interoperable, modern RSA-based `Cipher` instance with a few lines of code:

```java
    private static final String RSA_CIPHER_SPEC = "RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding";


    private static Cipher getRsaCipher(int direction, Key key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_CIPHER_SPEC);
        OAEPParameterSpec oaepSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        cipher.init(direction, key, oaepSpec);

        return cipher;
    }
```

and this can be used in your encryption/decryption methods like so:

```java
    public static byte[] decryptByPrivateKey(byte[] data, String key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = getRsaCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }

    public static byte[] encryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = getRsaCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }
```

on both the Android and Java sides.

There are other improvements that can be made to your code, for example eliminate base64 encoding/decoding. It seems to add complication with no benefits.

Comment: Thanks, its helped me. Thanks also for the details about «RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding»