# How to implement RSA based on custom user defined padding -JAVA

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, deterministic, secure-random

Im trying to implement RSA based on custom padding value.

```
cipher.init(ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey,oaepParameter, secureRandom);
```

I would like to change the secureRandom function to somthing else. Basically like to feed custom defined byte[] (could be random/ based on specific logic) to the Cipher init method.
Is there any way i can acheive this

Comment: Your best bet is to use the "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" transformation specification and then perform your own custom padding before encryption.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, Is there no other way to change the existing padding methods to take custom byte array as input for padding ?
I could see options in python but not in java.
Like in python 

`PKCS1_OAEP.new( self.pubkey,hashAlgo=,mgfunc=,randfunc=)`
 
do we have somthing like this in java

Comment: You can supply your own `SecureRandom` implementation, but it's a little tricky. There should be examples of that here on Stack Overflow, I think I might even have an answer on that. See [my answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76448352/238704) for how to choose the hash function and MGF hash function in OAEP padding.